# On the Users page, would it be better to sort horizontally instead of vertically?

Tags: discussion, design

Whenever I look at the users page, I expect the top row to be the highest rep users and so on down the line. It looks strange to me that it is sorted into columns instead. Anyone else think so?

Comment: There is something visually nice about the "top row".  I wasn't confused by the layout, but I could see why it would be better the other way.  I doubt you'll find much interest in UI redesign for that kind of detail though.

Answer (score 3):

What is really needed, if anything, is a visual separator to lead a user's eye in the right direction (vertically or horizontally).

Answer (score 1):

It would be no better to sort horizontally than vertically. I'm not saying that vertically is better either.

This does seem a trivial issue though, and changing it after 2 years would confuse more people than it helped.

Comment: Wow, I didn't realize this forum has been around 2 years!

Comment: @Michael: This _particular_ one has not. However the hugely successful [one that started it all](http://stackoverflow.com/) has. Anytime you see us refer to SO that's what we're referring to. A lot of this sites user-base has come from there.

Comment: Ah, right. Which, come to think of it, I've used once or twice.

Answer (score 1):

Don't change it!

Its taken me ages to make sure I have just enough, but not too much, rep to fool you into thinking I'm just behind hobodave.